# How to use a fingerprint device for a webapp authentication?

Tags: javascript, php, authentication, fingerprint, biometrics

I would like to use a fingerprint device for a WebApp authentication using the following technologies:
-HTML5, Javascript, PHP, LINUX, MYSQL.

I don't have any fingerprint device preference as long as it will do the job, and I'm not much concerned about high-security level.

Could you please tell me how possible it is to achieve my goal or is there any recommendation for fingerprint devices that provides WebAPI's for easy integration, using the technologies mentioned above?

Comment: JavaScript running in the browser won't have access to your fingerprint device so this is probably a non-starter. Don't you think if it was possible to do fingerprint authentication to a website that at least one of the big sites would have already done it by now?

Comment: https://youtu.be/eDP0U7DVw-4 There is a video which explains how to do the integration of fingerprint scanner with web applications. Check, if it helps

Comment: Great! @Ramshri,  I have been looking for something like this.  But I don't need any subscription to the service provider,  at least a once of payment would have been better.

Comment: Yes. One time license is provided. You can check with sales@camsunit.com